# Prove that the algebraic expressions are equivalent.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2} + 3^{k+1} = \frac{3^{k+2}-1}{2}$$

with steps make left hand side = right hand side by modifying one or both expressions

Thanks for your help guys, I solved it like this:

> $$\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2} + 3^{k+1} = \frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2} + \frac{2*3^{k+1}}{2} = \frac{3^{k+2}-1}{2} $$

Comment: $3^{k+1}+2\cdot 3^{k+1}=(1+2)\cdot 3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^{k+1}=3^{k+2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${3^{k+1}-1\over 2}+3^{k+1}={3^{k+1}\over 2}-{1\over 2}+{2(3^{k+1})\over 2}=({3\over 2})3^{k+1}-{1\over 2}={3^{k+2}-1\over 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $3^{k+1} = \dfrac{2\cdot 3^{k+1}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $$
2\cdot 3^{k+1}=(3-1)\cdot 3^{k+1}
$$